# Set Customize Response for Reactive Web Service using Spring Boot and MongoDB as backend

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming

I am developing reactive-spring-boot web service and also using reactive-mongodb to store data. I want to return my customize response for API. example as below:

```
[
      {
          "result": [
        {
          "code": "",
          "data": "",
          "error": ""
        }
      ]
    }
```

Sample Method:

```
@PostMapping(value="/addEmployee")

  public Mono<Response> addEmployeeDetails(Employee employee){

    Response response = new Response();

     if(employee.getEmpID() == null){
          return response(getResponse());
     }

     Repository.save(employee);

     return response(getResponse());
}
```

As you see in the code I have response() method which builds the required response.But it mono gives default response as below:
{
    "timestamp": "2018-09-29T16:23:21.287+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/employee"
}

I am not able to set my own status code and error message.

Comment: stacktrace? Whats the response method doing?

Comment: Hi Darren,  Response is my POJO.

Comment: There's an un-handled error making it up past the the mvc call, without a stack trace and/or the application itself it's hard to tell what the root cause is :)

Comment: I am writing a reactive web services. In one of the API I have added checks using if statement as given in code. eg:

if(employee.getEmpID() == null){
          return response(getResponse());
     }

How can I return customize error message here ? 

I get default error message as:

{ "timestamp": "2018-09-29T16:23:21.287+0000", "status": 500, "error": "Internal Server Error", "message": "Internal Server Error", "path": "/employee" }

But I want to print:

[
  {
      "result": [ {
          "code": "",
          "data": "",
          "error": ""
        }
      ]

Comment: Ah, got you. You need to provide onError within the reactive chain, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51024279/how-to-handle-errors-in-spring-reactor-mono-or-flux

Comment: Actually I am want to do data validation before saving the data in MongoDB. So whatever data I get in ServiceRequest or request body. I need to do validation for it and is the data is not proper then throw error. So if you check my if condition I need to send a user response (customize response) using Mono.